# login automatically a user from Wordpress in Laravel

Tags: laravel, wordpress, autologin

I'm trying to use Wordpress as a frontend CMS/Shop and Laravel as a platform that provide more advanced services to users that acquire them from WP frontend shop. After logging to Wordpress they'll have in account a link to Laravel dashboard where they have all they're acquired services. For extracting data from WP I'm using Corcel but I need users already logged in to be automatically authenticated in Laravel.

All discussions I found are related to using same users, or login the other way, from Laravel to WP. Wp and laravel are on same domain, wp in root and laravel in a /laravel dir and they;re working ok. I tried a hook on login to call laravel inside wp but this would run a parallel instance of Laravel.

this in WP as a hook in funtions.php not working:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wplaravel/vendor/autoload.php';$app = include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wplaravel/bootstrap/app.php';$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');$kernel->handle($request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture());

$id = (isset($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']]) ? $app['encrypter']->decrypt($_COOKIE[$app['config']['session.cookie']], false) : null);

if ($id) {
    $app['session']->driver()->setId(explode('|', $id)[1]);
    $app['session']->driver()->start();

    // Session::all();
    // $app['auth']->getSession(); //  Illuminate\Session\Store
    // Auth::user();
    // $app['auth']->user();
    
    // $user = App\User::find(1);
  $userl = App\Models\User::where('email',$user->data->user_email)->first();
  Auth::login($userl);
  //session()->put('wpuser', $user->data->user_email);
  //print_r(session()->all());

}
```

I need to have a user that login to Wordpress to be able to be authorized in Laravel without logging in there also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your idea is completely wrong if you are trying login from wp to laravel.

Here you need to do following

1.Redirect the user to laravel application with a wp session or verified secret

```
wp_redirect( "laravelapp.com?secure=secretcodes );
```

2.Verify the secret from laravel with the given secret

```
 $verify = $request->secure;
   if($verify == "secretcodes"){
     //verify your own logic here
   }
```

3.Find the desired user and use this code bellow in any controller that you redirect from wp to laravel

```
$user = User::find(1);
Auth::login($user);
```

Then it will be logged in into laravel applicaiton

Comment: How do you do numbers 1,2,3, in your answer? This answer isn't very descriptive. Why would someone find this helpful?

Comment: The question itself is very broad and almost a feature . so that would be very big to give the answer itself fully .

Comment: So, your answer is incomplete, and doesn't really answer the question?  Why would someone upvote your answer then? [answer]

Comment: ok, changed to post call to Laravel route, but still not working, ignore security / secret verification as for now is just for validating the concept

Comment: you dont need to redirect the user as post call , just redirect the user to your laravel application with some parameters , validate the parameters with your logic and then use my answer code to login the user into your laravel application. @tehnic

Comment: i have also updated my answer @tehnic

Answer (score 0):

If your WordPress users also have a mobile number, this might be a good option for you.

It works like this in Laravel :

```
$user = User::query()->where(('mobile',$requset->mobile)->first();

Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: the problem is that the session started in WP is not se same as accessing Laravel in url...seems to be parallel aps